# Searching An Unsorted Array for Inexact Match

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to count the number of lines since a value (in this case, price) has changed by 1% or more, but the data is sorted by time instead of by price. An example below:

1. $1.000
2. $1.005
3. $1.000
4. $0.995
5. $0.990

My instinct is to use MATCH, but since the price array is unsorted and the price may not be exactly = value * +/- 0.01, I'm having a hard time making that work.

The other thing that might work is sorting by price, but then I'm having a hard time counting the number of line items that would fall between the price changes. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a loop in a macro perhaps?

Comment: That would certainly work, but it will have to run the macro once for each line, for up to 50,000 entries, and I am concerned about run time for the macro.

Comment: So I'm not clear on what the output will be in the above example. I see two 1.0s and 0.99 and before that there is 1.005 and 0.995... do you output all?

Comment: I'm just wondering if calculating the differences and tracking each aggregate difference (0 values for row 1, 1 for row 2, 2 for row 3 and so on) would help. It might be inefficient unless there is some condition that lets you discard a set of aggregates after a point.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with the `COUNTIFS` forumula,

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<=" & (I1+(I1*0.01)),A:A,">=" & (I1-(I1*0.01)))`

Where A:A is the range of your data and I1 is the cell where you have the "value".
The formula basically counts all the numbers which are between `value+value*.01` and `value-value*.01`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I need to only count the occurrences until a 1% change occurs, i.e. I need to subtract away older occurrences in the target range. Is there a way to restrict countifs to contiguous arrays?

Comment: @zcallen am not understanding properly. Can you please explain with screenshots of your desired output and how you achieved it